# How to emphasize the word "do"

Tags: перевод

How would you counter someone that says something false, such as, "You don't speak Russian," then you say, "I **do** speak Russian!"? But how do you emphasize the *do* part?

Comment: "Ты не говоришь по-руский" is wrong and ungrammatical sentence.

Comment: @Anixx How do you word it?

Comment: @Anixx whenever you can edit, it's just more efficient to edit the question rather then point to an error - the author still will notice it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing like "do" as an auxiliary verb in Russian, thus, there's not such thing like direct analog. But here's a list of phrases than more or less convey the same as the "I do" construction:

1. *(colloquial)* А вот и [нет,] говорю!
2. *(even more colloquial, even childish)*  - Очень даже и говорю!
3. *(more neutral)* Да нет, [почему], говорю. (The same "отчего же, говорю")
4. *(bookish)* Напротив, говорю.
5. *(even more bookish)* Отнюдь, говорю.

Comment: Можно без добавлений, просто "говорю."Или в более распространенном предложении с логическим ударением на глагол.

Comment: @V.V. просто "говорю" соответствует "I speak Russian" rather than "I do speak Russian"!

Comment: Просто "говорю" в ответе соответствует ответу But I do (speak. Russian ).

Comment: "Нет, говорю" проще всего.

Comment: How would you just say "I do" or "He doesn't" on their own?

Answer (score 3):

This kind of "do" is not indicated in the text. All possible variants are either bookish or colloquial. An exact equivalent is emphasized by intonation.

- Вы не говорите по-русски.
- **Я́** говорю. (default is "Я говорю́").

Additional words, such as "-то" in "я-то говорю" instead of the intonation change indicates the intention of the speaker to argue. Only the intonation change is as plain and simple, as "do".

Comment: That's true, it could be two different stresses on Я. "Вы не говорите по-русски. - Я́ говорю" or "И кто это говорит? - Я́ говорю". Spells the same, sounds differently.